# What is a MultiRolePool Azure Resource

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have an arm template and it has a Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/multiRolePools resource.  I am not able to find any documentation on this and was wondering if anyone could help pin point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can refer to [App Service Environments - List Multi Role Pool Instance Metric Definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-environments/list-multi-role-pool-instance-metric-definitions),  [App Service Environments - List Multi Role Usages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-environments/list-multi-role-usages), and  [App Service Environments - List Multi Role Pool Skus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-environments/list-multi-role-pool-skus)

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/multiRolePools` is one of the Supported metrics in Azure Monitor.

You can explore more on this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftwebhostingenvironmentsmultirolepools